# Powershell v2 use textbox to continously output text

Tags: powershell, textbox

I have a Powershell v2 script that processes files and continuously outputs text information to the console. In addition. I want to output this text to a textbox form. I have figured out how to show a textbox, but have not found a way of continuously adding text to the textbox after it is displayed with the `ShowDialog` Method. Can this be achieved in Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

In my sapien powershell forms, I usually set the .text value to equal itself + a few vbcrlf, then append the new output.

```
$textbox.text = $textbox.text  + "`r`n`r`n" + $append_output
```

or this `+=` will do the same trick

```
$textbox.text += "`r`n`r`n" + $append_output
```

Though I'd recommend the richtextbox over textbox if you want better formatting.